# Show that a subset $A$ of $R$ is open iff it is countable union of open intervals

Tags: general-topology

Let me prove subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is open if and only if it is a countable union of open intervals.

For all $x \in A$ there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ is an open interval contained in $A$. Now find rationals such that $r_{x} \in (x-\epsilon,x)$ and $s_{x} \in (x,x+\epsilon)$ and $A = \bigcup_{x \in A}(r_{x},s_{x})$. Note that the intervals with rational end points is less than $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$. Obviously $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

My doubt is that instead of selecting rationals can I select **irrationals**.

Comment: I edited your question a bit and added a bit of clarification. I had to make some assumptions about what you meant, so let me know if any of them were off the mark

Comment: Surely you want to prove that a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open iff it is a countable union of disjoint intervals?

Comment: @Pete.No.Need not be disjoint intervals.

Comment: The point being that in any context you know in which open sets make sense, it is more or less a triviality to show that any union of open subsets is open, and any open subset is a union of even one open subset (itself).  What I suggested above is a more contentful standard exercise that is particular to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Anyway, what I suggested above is at least a true fact that one might try to prove.

Comment: This is known as Lindelof's Lemma http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f%27s_lemma

Comment: @Pete: $\mathbf{R}$ is not a union of disjoint intervals (I consider intervals to be bounded, and the unbounded ones I call segments). Like in my answer: there are countably many disjoint components, but these are only intervals if you consider the whole set $\mathbf{R}$ and all segments like $(0, +\infty)$ to be "intervals" too.

Comment: @Henno: OK.  Your linguistic conventions are certainly reasonable, but just FYI: in English (and especially American) usage, a very common definition of an interval is such as to render the following fact true: "A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is connected iff it is an interval".  (Well, let's not fight about the empty set...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ is locally connected, so the connected components of open sets are open.
So if $O$ is open, write it as the (disjoint) union of its connected components, which are open (as said) and connected and thus intervals or segments, or $\mathbb{R}$ itself.
As all of these are (at most countable) unions of intervals. Because every different component must contain a different member of $\mathbb{Q}$, there are at most countably many components, and thus countably many intervals to write $O$ as a union all together.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should change your statement: instead of "open subsets" you should say "open intervals". Otherwise, as Pete L. Clark observes, every open set is the union of *one* open subset, namely itself.

As for your proof, I don't see how you can assure the existence of your rational numbers $r_x$ and $s_x$ such that $A = \bigcup_{x\in A} (r_x, s_x)$ and indeed there is no need for doing so.

Instead, I would proceed as Henno Brandsma, but let me write it using less results perhaps: if you have an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}$, for every point $x\in U$ there exists an open interval $I_x$ such that $x\in I_x \subset U$, by definition of open sets of the real line (with the standard topology). Hence $U = \bigcup_{x\in U} I_x$.

Now, pick a rational number $r_x \in I_x$ for every $x\in U$. You can do this because rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Since there is only a countable number of rational numbers, you're done.

(And yes: you could also pick an irrational number for each $x$: so what?)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think picking a rational number as the upper and lower bound is correct. Let A be your open set. Then define, for each  $x \in A$, $$r_x = inf \lbrace x_0 : (x_0,x) \subset A \rbrace$$ $$s_x = sup \lbrace x_0 : (x,x_0) \subset A \rbrace$$ Then $(r_x,s_x)$ will be the maximal open interval containing $x$ that is a subset of $A$ as well. In particular, you can show that the endpoints to not belong into these intervals, and secondly, that for two points $x,y \in A$, the intervals $(r_x,s_x)$ and $(r_y,s_y)$ are either disjoint or equal (by maximality). Then note that you can only have a countable amount of *disjoint* open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ (select a rational number in each...).